# How to solve T(n) = T(n-1) + n(n-1)?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis

I am not able to solve the following recurrence relation:

T(n)={T(n−1)+n(n-1) if n≥2,T(1)=1.

Comment: Why not? Help us help you: what have you tried, where's your problem? Unfortunately for you, this site isn't an answering service. BTW, welcome!

Comment: When I solve it the output is: ( n^2 -2n )
But on a site wolframalpha.com the output 
( T(n) = 1/3 (n^3 - n + 3) ) different from my output 
I don't know where my fault is

Answer (score 2):

Here's a useful rule of thumb.

A recurrence of the form

$$T(n) = T(n-1) + p(n)$$

where $p$ is a polynomial has the solution

$$T(n) = q(n)$$

where $q$ is a polynomial one degree higher than $p$.

I'm going to give you an example, and leave you to solve your own problem. The example is the sum-of-cubes formula:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}S(0) & = & 0 \\ S(n) & = & S(n-1) + n^3\end{eqnarray*}$$

We look for a quartic solution:

$$S(n) = a_4 n^4 + a_3 n^3 + a_2 n^2 + a_1 n + a_0$$

The base case gives:

$$a_0 = S(0) = 0$$

And the inductive case gives:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}& & a_4 n^4 + a_3 n^3 + a_2 n^2 + a_1 n + a_0 \\ & =& a_4 (n-1)^4 + a_3 (n-1)^3 + a_2 (n-1)^2 + a_1 (n-1) + a_0+ n^3\end{eqnarray*}$$

That is:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}& & a_4 n^4 + a_3 n^3 + a_2 n^2 + a_1 n + a_0 \\ & =& a_4 (n-1)^4 + a_3 (n-1)^3 + a_2 (n-1)^2 + a_1 (n-1) + a_0+ n^3\end{eqnarray*}$$

$$(4a_4-1)n^3+(3a_3-6a_4)n^2+(4a_4-3a_3+2a_2)n+(-a_4+a_3-a_2+a_1) = 0$$

Because this must be true for all $n$, we get the system of equations:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}4a_4 - 1 & = & 0 \\ 3a_3-6a_4 & = & 0 \\ 4a_4-3a_3+2a_2 & = & 0 \\ -a_4+a_3-a_2+a_1 & = & 0\end{eqnarray*}$$

Four equations in four unknowns. Solve this:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}a_4 & = & \frac{1}{4} \\ a_3 & = & \frac{1}{2} \\ a_2 & = & \frac{1}{4} \\ a_1 & = & 0\end{eqnarray*}$$

Therefore:

$$S(n) = \frac{1}{4} n^4 + \frac{1}{2} n^3 + \frac{1}{4} n^2$$

Now try solving your problem.